# Vector equation involving $\nabla\dot{}(\overrightarrow A\times\overrightarrow B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I have to solve the following equation:
$\nabla\dot{}(\overrightarrow u\times\overrightarrow v)=\overrightarrow u\dot{}\overrightarrow v$
where $\overrightarrow u$ and$\overrightarrow v$ are defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\overrightarrow v$ is a known vector.
I know that:
$\nabla\dot{}(\overrightarrow A\times\overrightarrow B)=B\dot{}\nabla\times\overrightarrow A-\overrightarrow A\dot{}\nabla\times\overrightarrow B$, so I have:
$v\dot{}\nabla\times\overrightarrow u-\overrightarrow u\dot{}\nabla\times\overrightarrow v=\overrightarrow u\dot{}\overrightarrow v$, but it seems to be not so useful to solve the equation. Does somebody have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is unknown in the equation?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang: $\overrightarrow u$

Comment: The known vector is a constant. What's the derivative of a constant?

Comment: You seem to imply that  $\vec{v}$ is constant (as a vector function on $\mathbb{R}^3$). This implies that $\nabla \times \vec{v} = 0$, so your equation becomes $(\nabla \times \vec{u})\cdot\vec{v} = \vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$. It may be simpler to solve.

Comment: Not necessarily. $\overrightarrow v$ could be $\overrightarrow v(x,y,z)$ where $v(x,y,z)$ is a known function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the equation 
$$\nabla\cdot(u\times v)-u\cdot v=(v\times\nabla)\cdot u-(\nabla\times v+v)\cdot u=0$$
This is a linear first order pde and hence the solution for $u$ exists. Considering there's only one equation for three unknowns $u_x,u_y,u_z$, we can write infinite solutions up to scalar. You could try to solve a special case where $u=u(x_1)$.